# Query the image data type in DigitalMicrograph script

Tags: image-processing, dm-script

How do I query the image data type and size with a digitalmicrograph (DM) script?  I want to find out if the image is signed or unsigned, real or integer, the size of the pixel, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are commands to return this info as a return value, and some which query for a specific type. You find the commands in the following F1 help section:

[image]

Here is some example code:

```
number byteIN = 4
number sx = 10, sy = 10
image test := RealImage( "Test", byteIN, sx, sy )

// General commands
number dataTypeEnum = test.ImageGetDataType()
Result( "Image is of data type " + dataTypeEnum + ".\n" )

number byte = test.ImageGetDataElementByteSize()
number bits = test.ImageGetDataElementBitSize()
Result( "Image has " + byte +" bytes/pixel ( =" + bits + "bits/pixel )\n" )

// Some specific commands (there are more), all return Boolean
if ( test.ImageIsDataTypeFloat() ) 
    Result( "Image is a real image.\n" )

if ( test.ImageIsDataTypeInteger() ) 
    Result( "Image is an integer image.\n" )

if ( test.ImageIsDataTypeBinary() ) 
    Result( "Image is a binary image.\n" )

if ( test.ImageIsDataTypeComplex() ) 
    Result( "Image is a complex image.\n" )
```